# Get associated products of group in parts

Tags: product, collection, product-collection

I need to load associate products in parts/portions.

I am showing 3 products default. After that I have added a link ("load more"). Once the user clicks on "load more", the next 3 products should be added in the table.

Maybe this could be DONE by Offset but how can I do this? I don't understand.

I don't know how I can get associate products collection.

Please help if any one know how I divide associated collection in parts/portions.

Below is my code

```
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->load('157902');
         $associatedProducts = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($product)->setCurPage(2)->setPageSize(2);
```

But collection is empty when I used offset , current page or page size

Comment: Would you be able to provide a bit more information regarding your issue?

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you are looking for, `setCurPage` is the start of the Offset, and `setPageSize` is the number of items return starting from the offset:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->load('157902');
$_simples = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped')->getAssociatedProductCollection($product)->setCurPage(0)->setPageSize(2);
foreach ($_simples as $key => $value) {
    Zend_Debug::dump($value->getEntityId());
}
```

Comment: But Its showing Nothing on browser :( I want grouped product assciated products not for configurable. Is there any way?

Comment: Updated answer, note the model and method called changed. I don't have any grouped products in my local environment at the moment to verify but this should work.